How do I Remove Indicator Script Version on Status Line?
CHART SAMPLE
How do I remove that number 29 on the upper left beside my script short titled EMA?
My other indicators don't display the version number but for some reason this EMA script does.
I tried looking in the script code and status line settings but I can't seem to find how to remove it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you sure that it is the version number and not just some plot? Could you please share your code?
